# Compare bash variable to see if divisible by 5

Tags: scripting, test, numeric-data

Here is my code; I want to compare `$COUNTER` to various multiple times.

```
if [ "$COUNTER" = "5" ]; then
```

It's okay, but I want it do it for **dynamic** times like `5,10,15,20` etc.

Comment: So do you want to check if `$COUNTER` is a *multiple* of 5?

Comment: yes like 5 , 10 , 15  or 200 , 400 , 600 something like that .

Comment: You didn't answer my question. How about 30 - it's also a multiple of 5, would it be ok?

Comment: Do you mean you want the "5" part to be a variable instead of just "5", so that you're comparing $COUNTER to another variable, or do you want to see if $COUNTER is a multiple of five?

Comment: Your title leads me to think that you're wanting to ask if $COUNTER is one of a set of values: "is it 5 or 10 or 15 or 20 or 200 or ..."? If that's correct, what's that set of values? How are they determined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conclusion of the various comments seems to be that the simplest answer to the original question is

```
if ! (( $COUNTER % 5 )) ; then
```

Comment: Yes, if the particular shell in question understand that syntax. Bash and a few other major shells do.

Comment: @Kusalananda in which case something like `if (( (k/5)*5 == k ))` or even ``if [ $k -ne `expr $k / 5 \* 5` ]``

Comment: @roaima It's the double parentheses that is the issue, not the modulus operator.

Comment: Why is there an exclamation mark in front? It makes the expression look like finding non-divisible numbers...

Comment: Because it's examining the remainder of counter divided by 5.  If result is 0, then it's divisible by 5.  If the result is anything else, it's not divisible by 5.  Hence the need for `!`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the modulo arithmetic operator:

```
#!/bin/sh

counter="$1"
remainder=$(( counter % 5 ))
echo "Counter is $counter"
if [ "$remainder" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'its a multiple of 5'
else
    echo 'its not a multiple of 5'
fi
```

In use:

```
$ ./modulo.sh 10
Counter is 10
its a multiple of 5
$ ./modulo.sh 12
Counter is 12
its not a multiple of 5
$ ./modulo.sh 300
Counter is 300
its a multiple of 5
```

I've also written a loop that may be what you are looking for?  This will loop through every number from 1 to 600 and check if they are multiples of 5:

**loop.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 600 ]; do
        remainder=$(( i % 5 ))
        [ "$remainder" -eq 0 ] && echo "$i is a multiple of 5"
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

**output** (shortened)

```
$ ./loop.sh
5 is a multiple of 5
10 is a multiple of 5
15 is a multiple of 5
20 is a multiple of 5
25 is a multiple of 5
30 is a multiple of 5
...
555 is a multiple of 5
560 is a multiple of 5
565 is a multiple of 5
570 is a multiple of 5
575 is a multiple of 5
580 is a multiple of 5
585 is a multiple of 5
590 is a multiple of 5
595 is a multiple of 5
600 is a multiple of 5
```

Comment: and for 200 , 400 , 600 ?

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi 200, 400, and 600 are also multiples of 5...

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to enclose a number with `""`?

Comment: i mean $COUNTER=200 & 300 & 400 etc ..

Comment: In bash, can't this be simplified to just `if ((counter%5 == 0)); then ...` ?

Comment: @steeldriver:  Yes.

Comment: or `if ! ((counter%5)); then...`

Comment: I have made my answer in `sh` because op is using `[` rather than `[[`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes. In the (unlikely) event that `$IFS` contains a digit.

Comment: @Kusalananda: also in `arithmetic expansions`? My `Bash 4.3.46` returns error when number is enclosed in `""`: `./modulo.sh: line 5: "7"%5: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""7"%5")`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk In an arithmetic context (inside `$(( ... ))`) quotes and `$` are not needed. I thought you were talking about the `[ ... ]` test`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: *not needed* implies that they are optional, are they legal at all? OP changed his answer, he used `""` in `$((...))` before.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Not the quotes.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I don't understand.  What do you mean by `not the quotes`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk The quotes are not legal inside `$(( ... ))`, as far as I can tell.  The `$` on variable names is optional.

Comment: @Kusalananda: ok, that's what I meant in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question *exactly* as it's currently written, disregarding the title (which was edited).

To compare an integer in a variable to a number of other integer values, where the other values are determined ahead of time (it is unclear what "dynamically" actually means in the question):

```
case "$value" in
    5|10|15|200|400|600)
        echo 'The value is one of those numbers' ;;
    *)
        echo 'The value is not one of those numbers'
esac
```

This may also be done in a loop, of course,

```
for i in 5 10 15 200 400 600; do
    if [ "$value" -eq "$i" ]; then
        echo 'The value is one of those numbers'
        break
    fi
done
```

But this makes it harder to handle the case when `$value` is *not* found among the given numbers without using some sort of flag:

```
found=0
for i in 5 10 15 200 400 600; do
    if [ "$value" -eq "$i" ]; then
        echo 'The value is one of those numbers'
        found=1
        break
    fi
done

if [ "$found" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'The value is not one of those numbers'
fi
```

Or, cleaner,

```
found=0
for i in 5 10 15 200 400 600; do
    if [ "$value" -eq "$i" ]; then
        found=1
        break
    fi
done

if [ "$found" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo 'The value is one of those numbers'
else
    echo 'The value is not one of those numbers'
fi
```

I would personally go for the `case ... esac` implementation.